# Secondary Selection beginning end

Tags: secondary-selection

How can I programmatically define a secondary selection with beginning and end defined?;)

I try to look for this, but only find mouse usage;)

Any pointers?;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use library [`second-sel.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/second-sel.el) to do what you want (and more) with secondary selections. See description [here](https://emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection#second-sel.el), along with other info about the secondary selection.

In particular, you can set the secondary selection using Lisp code or using the keyboard. And you can have a ring of secondary selections, just like the  ring (`kill-ring`) of primary selections.

Here are some key bindings you might want to use:

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-y")               'secondary-yank|select|move|swap)
(define-key esc-map "y"                     'yank-pop-commands)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-M-y")  'isearch-yank-secondary)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-M-SPC")         'set-secondary-start)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-M-<return>")    'secondary-save-then-kill)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-<mouse-3>")       'mouse-secondary-save-then-kill)
```

But the quick answer to your question is to just do this, where BEG and END are the limits you want for the secondary selection:

```lisp
(secondary-swap-region BEG END)
```